# aggregation on JSON in flink using Java

Tags: java, json, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am reading JSON data from a file.

**Sample Data**

```
{"name":"user1","myparam0":false,"myparam1":"44750004-23df-4960-88be-ba0884291597","myparam2":"36A3BF29-23df-EE2A-76B9-19BC1C854BA7","myparam3":"http://www.seloger.com/","myparam4":"http://www.seloger.com/erreur-temporaire/husk-pie","ver":"4.0.0"}
{"name":"user1","myparam0":true,"myparam1":"44750004-8bff-4960-88be-ba0884291597","myparam2":"36A3BF29-88be-EE2A-76B9-19BC1C854BA7","myparam3":"","myparam4":"http://www.seloger.com/erreur-temporaire/binde","ver":"4.0.0"}
```

I have written a sample code to read from the file and converted data to JSON like this

```
DataStream<Object> input = env.readTextFile("file:///home/ravisankar/workspace/temporary/input.file")
                .map((line) -> {
                    return JSON.parseFull(line);
                });
```

Now I need to calculate how many `myparam3` are empty in 15 seconds based on the name. and group by `myparam4`

```
Ex: {
  "user1": {
    "myparams3": 1,
    "myparam4": {
      "http://www.seloger.com/erreur-temporaire/binde": 1,
      "http://www.seloger.com/erreur-temporaire/husk-pie": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to extract such data like this from Flink?? I don't see any examples working on JSON using Java. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You could parse your json string to object i.e. via jackson library and operate a stream of java objects as usual

Answer (score 1):

you can use jackson to parse the json to an object then make a loop to count your elements

```
private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper() ;
...
Object element = objectMapper.readValue( jsonString , Object.class );
```

or you can use a regex that matches *"myparam3":""* and calculate tha matches

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{
    String str = "{\"name\":\"user1\",\"myparam0\":false,\"myparam1\":\"44750004-23df-4960-88be-ba0884291597\",\"myparam2\":\"36A3BF29-23df-EE2A-76B9-19BC1C854BA7\",\"myparam3\":\"http://www.seloger.com/\",\"myparam4\":\"http://www.seloger.com/erreur-temporaire/husk-pie\",\"ver\":\"4.0.0\"}\r\n" + 
            "{\"name\":\"user1\",\"myparam0\":true,\"myparam1\":\"44750004-8bff-4960-88be-ba0884291597\",\"myparam2\":\"36A3BF29-88be-EE2A-76B9-19BC1C854BA7\",\"myparam3\":\"\",\"myparam3\":\"\",\"myparam3\":\"\"\"myparam4\":\"http://www.seloger.com/erreur-temporaire/binde\",\"ver\":\"4.0.0\"}";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"myparam3\":\"\"");


    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Matches found : " + count );
}
```

Comment: I have many ways to do this counting job. With this I can do only counting of `myparam3`. But along with that I need the `myparam4` groupby values also. How can I do that??

Comment: if you choose the regex option you can use a _Map<String,String>_ you can use this function in the answer, you can make it take the paramName and return the count of that param or its value depending on what you need

Comment: ps: the regex is better if you have a very huge Json-file that wouldn't fit in memory and you need to read it line by line , Otherway loading the json into an object with Jackson then processing it, is a better way